How to change a langauge without deprecated updateConfiguration() method Java Android studio
I am doing this mobile app in Java and I want to have language selection. I managed to this in way below, but I don't want to use deprecated updateConfiguration() method, but I couldn't find working alternative
public class LanguageHandler {
    public static final String ENGLISH_LANG_CODE = "en";
    public static final String POLISH_LANG_CODE = "pl";
    private static String currentLanguage = ENGLISH_LANG_CODE;

    public static void setLanguage(@NonNull Context context, String languageCode) {
        if (languageCode.equalsIgnoreCase(currentLanguage)) {
            return;
        }

        Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLocales(new android.os.LocaleList(locale));
        Context updatedContext = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        if (context instanceof Activity && !languageCode.equalsIgnoreCase(currentLanguage)) {
            currentLanguage = languageCode;
            Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            activity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, updatedContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            activity.recreate();
        }
    }
}

This is how i use this class in my Activity
    private void setUpLanguageSelector() {
        RadioGroup languageSelector = findViewById(R.id.language_selector);
        languageSelector.check(R.id.lang_english);
        languageSelector.setOnCheckedChangeListener((radioGroup, checkedID) -> {
            if(checkedID == R.id.lang_english) {
                setLanguage(StartViewActivity.this, ENGLISH_LANG_CODE);
            } else if (checkedID == R.id.lang_polish) {
                setLanguage(StartViewActivity.this, POLISH_LANG_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

Could someone help me with an alternative approach or suggest how I could adjust my project structure to make it work without deprecated method? If my current structure is causing the issue, I would appreciate advice on how to proceed.
